# How to fix "Compile Error: Object Required" error?

Tags: vba, excel

This is my very first time with VBA. For the following code fragment:

```
Dim i As Integer
    Set i = 0
    For Each v In dictDT.Keys
        Cells(10, 5 + i) = dictDT.Item(v)
        i = i + 1
    Next
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Compile Error: Object Required
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not up to date on my VB, so I ask: do you need to specify a `type` for `v`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change

```
Set i = 0
```

to

```
i = 0
```

Only objects require the Set keyword.  Other variable types do not.